# js: Using a try/catch when not concerned about the specific error

Tags: javascript

I have a a file name that comes from a file uploaded by the user

```
 const fileName = "foo.doc"
```

I then went to pass that to an api that saves this to storage.

```
 const mydata = await myApiToSaveFile(fileName);
```

// if the server throws an error even after my sanitization, I want to just pass in a UUID, which I know will pass.  I don't care about the specific error, just that an error occurs, so is it wrong to use a try/catch for this?

```
try { 
    const mydata = await myApiToSaveFile(fileName);
} catch(e) {
   const mydata = await myApiToSaveFile(generateUUID());
}
```

Comment: Might make more sense to adjust the API to accept another parameter if the first fails, that way there's only one request

Comment: You’re not using the specific error, so what’s the issue here? Yes, `try`–`catch` is fine here. You can also remove the `(e)`; that’s the optional catch binding feature ([original proposal](//github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-catch-binding), [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#the_exception_identifier)).